# How to use a jQuery selector using an Id set dynamically by Angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I"m building a small app to test different possibilities for a demonstration.
This app is a kind of personnal "Trip Advisor" for pubs in my area. For each pub, I store a name, a mark and its location.

I have 3 pages in the app :

- Displaying all pubs : *pubList.html*
- Adding a pub : *addPub.html*
- Showing one pub detail : *pubDetail.html*

I navigate from *pubList* to *pubDetail* by a simple click on the element. The *pubDetail* controler gets the pub index using $routeParams.

My goal is to display a googleMaps showing where the pub is, using the stored coordonates. Problem is, if the first pub is displayed perfectly, the second (when coming back to *pubList* and openning another pub) doesn't work.
I had the idea to inject the index on the bar in the mapContainer div like this :

**pubDetail Controleur**

```
app.controller("pubDetailControler", function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {  
    //Local pub
    $scope.localPub = $rootScope.pubList[$routeParams.index];
    $scope.localPub.index = $routeParams.index;
}
```

**pubDetail View**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>{{localPub.name}}</h1>
    <div id="mapContainer-{{ localPub.index }}"></div>
</div>
```

Using the code explorer, I confirm the div Id is correctly set (mapContainer-0, mapContainer-1, ...)
However, when I try to use a jQuery Selector on this div, it doesn't work. My theory is the div ID isn't yet set when the coed reaches the selector, failing it.
My jQuery selector is as follow :

```
$("#mapContainer-" + $scope.localPub.index).css({ "width": "300px", "height": "300px", "background-color": "lightgrey" });
```

By the way, if my jQuery selector fails, the google maps instanciation fails as well :

```
var tmpMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer-' + $scope.barLocal.index), [...]);
```

Does anyone have a idea how I can interact with this div ?

## =====================================================

EDIT : here is the (simplified yet complete) code of the *pubList* and *pubDetail* elements. The code is in french, but it's small enough to be understood perfectly I think.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="monBarAdvisor">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src *">
    <title>BarAdvisor</title>

    <!—Feuilles de style -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Librairies externes -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB2Czg7F2iw6Zz0JMebInmofW4e83aPsB8"></script>

    <!-- Référence Cordova ajoutée à votre application une fois générée. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!--Librairies personnelles-->
    <script src="lib/index.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/controleurs/afficherBar.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/controleurs/barsControleur.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="pull-left"><a href="#/">Tous</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#/ajouteBar">Ajouter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <!-- Contenu -->
    <div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('monBarAdvisor', ['ngRoute','ngCordova']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            "templateUrl": "vues/bars.html",
            "controller": "barsControleur"
        })
        .when("/ajouteBar", {
            "templateUrl": "vues/ajouterBar.html",
            "controller": "ajouterBarControleur"
        })
        .when("/bar/:index", {
            "templateUrl": "vues/afficherBar.html",
            "controller": "afficherBarControleur"
        })
        .otherwise({ "redirectTo": "/" });
});

//Gestionnaire d'erreur
function errorHandler(pMessage) {
    return function () { console.log(pMessage); }
}
```

**pubList view, named here *bars.html***

```
<div ng-repeat="tmpBar in listeBars">
    <a href="#/bar/{{ $index }}">
        <div>
            <p class="bar_nom">{{tmpBar.nom}}</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==0}}">☆☆☆☆☆</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==1}}">★☆☆☆☆</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==2}}">★★☆☆☆</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==3}}">★★★☆☆</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==4}}">★★★★☆</p>
            <p class="bar_note" ng-show="{{tmpBar.note==5}}">★★★★★</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**pubList controler, named here *barsControleur***

```
app.controller("barsControleur", function ($scope, $rootScope, $route) {

    $rootScope.listeBars = [
      {"nom":"Milton Pub","note":"4","geolocation":{"lat":"45.8982901","long":"6.1223147"}},
      {"nom":"Captain Pub","note":"4","geolocation":{"lat":"45.8984964","long":"6.1235909"}},
      {"nom":"Le Grand Café","note":"2","geolocation":{"lat":"45.8983107","long":"6.121416"}}
    ];

    $route.reload();
});
```

**pubDetail view, named here *afficherBar***

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>{{barLocal.nom}}</h1>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==0}}">☆☆☆☆☆</div>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==1}}">★☆☆☆☆</div>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==2}}">★★☆☆☆</div>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==3}}">★★★☆☆</div>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==4}}">★★★★☆</div>
    <div class="barLocal_note" ng-show="{{barLocal.note==5}}">★★★★★</div>
    <div id="conteneurCarte-{{ barLocal.index }}"></div>
    <div id="conteneurCarte"></div>
</div>
```

**pubDetail controler, named here *affiherBarControleur*, the code at fault**

```
app.controller("afficherBarControleur", function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {

    //Bar local
    $scope.barLocal = $rootScope.listeBars[$routeParams.index];
    $scope.barLocal.index = $routeParams.index;

    //Récupération de la carte via GoogleAPI
    $scope.recupereCarteGoogleAPI = function () {
        console.log('conteneurCarte-' + $scope.barLocal.index);
        $("#conteneurCarte-" + $scope.barLocal.index).css({ "width": "300px", "height": "300px", "background-color": "lightgrey" });
        $("#conteneurCarte").css({ "width": "300px", "height": "300px", "background-color": "green" });
    }

    if ($scope.barLocal.geolocation) {
        $scope.recupereCarteGoogleAPI();
    }

});
```

The console.log works great, but the .css() doesn't work a bit.

Comment: Can you share the whole thing? You can use jQuery and Angular together, but you do need to understand Angular works differently than a classic webpage with jQuery, and write your jQuery code with that change in mind.

Comment: I'd suggest using an angular library that provides you with directives to use Google maps, fe: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Comment: I'll post the code tomorrow, I can only "comment" today

Comment: Shouldn't be using jQuery for any of this. Suggest reading [Thinking in anjularjs when I have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: @sniels : edited the post with the complete code.

Comment: I'd suggest researching how to create apps in Angularjs more, maybe @charlietfl post will help. In an MVC pattern you should avoid writing view related code in your controller (styling, manipulating dom, etc). If you do need to do View related stuff that's too complicated with model binding, you should wrap that View logic in a directive. I'd suggest learning Angular without jQuery a little more.